# Dtype of type str but output of read_csv in Shell still of type int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new in python so it happens that on certain problems I'm getting really stuck from time to time. I have already checked the web not finding a proper solution.

I'm importing a CSV file having one column defined as `str` with

```
test_df=pd.read_csv(('Mappe41.csv'), dtype={'Payment Transaction ID':'str'} ...
```

Once I'm running the code the output on python shell and subsequently in Excel shows still the data as int. Any idea why? Here below the output:

[image: output].

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

It should be `string` instead of `str`. See [`pandas.DataFrame.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html)

```
test_df=pd.read_csv(('Mappe41.csv'), dtype={'Payment Transaction ID':'string'}
```